# How I style and label individual curves in a ParametricPlot?

Tags: plotting, legending, style

I have what I think is a `ParametricPlot` that is no different in structure from the example for explicitly styling different curves provided [in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html):

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[z[t,#]]&/@{3,4,5},
{t, 0, 10},
PlotLegends->{"foo","bar","baz"},
PlotStyle->{Red,Blue, Green}]
```

But this produces a figure with *one* rather than three styles and legends (oddly the last listed for the style and the first listed legend):

[image]

How do I get different styles and legends for each curve in my plot?

Comment: `ParametricPlot` has the attribute `HoldAll`.  I suspect you will get the result you want by wrapping `Evaluate` around the first argument to `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: We don't have your definition of `z`, but here's an example of what chuy is talking about, using another complex function:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/QX56X.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made up a `z[t]`.

```
z[t_, i_] := i (Cos[t] + I Sin[t]) + 0.2*(Cos[3 i t] + I Sin[3 i t])

ParametricPlot[
 ReIm[z[t, #]] & /@ {3, 4, 5},
 {t, 0, 10},
 PlotLegends -> {"foo", "bar", "baz"},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You need to wrap the `Map` with `Evaluate`.

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[ReIm[z[t, #]] & /@ {3, 4, 5}],
 {t, 0, 10},
 PlotLegends -> {"foo", "bar", "baz"},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]